# Not being able to understand the flutter docs

Tags: flutter, dart

I was referencing to the Flutter Docs, but I am not able to correctly read them. What I am trying to say is that I am not able to correctly understand them. I am having questions like "How would I know if a property accepts `Widget` or `double` or `MaterialStateProperty`?"

[image: elevation]

I was trying to understand the `elevatio`n property under `ButtonStyle` class under `ButtonStyleButton` class. It is written as:

```
elevation → MaterialStateProperty<double?>?
The elevation of the button's Material.
```

I can't understand this syntax. What will be the input of elevation if I am defining the custom ButtonClassButton class as following:

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundIconButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonStyleButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ButtonStyle(
        elevation: ?????????????,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MaterialState` enum provides interactive states that some of the Material widgets can take on when receiving input from the user. The `MaterialStateProperty<T>` class is an interface for classes that resolve to a value of type T based on a widget's interactive "state".

To provide more clarification, please refer the Static Methods under MaterialStateProperty class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html).

If you have a single value for all states (say 10.0 as the double value), you can set the elevation as follows:

```dart
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundIconButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonStyleButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ButtonStyle(
        elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(10),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```